# UITableViewCell AccessoryViews not showing in iOS6 but showing in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and in that I have to show check mark on the cell on its selection and have show detail disclosure on its deselect(if again select the row). My code is as follows :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator || cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton || cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }
    else if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
            cell.accessoryType = hasGroupID ? UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton : UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        else
            cell.accessoryType = hasGroupID ? UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton : UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

The problem here is, it's working perfectly on iOS 7 devices ,but on iOS 6, the accessory views are not appearing.

Need some guidance on what could be the issue here and what needs to be done to resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: check your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reloadData provoke that the UITableView will redraw entirely. The accessory set in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is cleared by the new call of cellForRowAtIndexPath in the datasource handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    checkedRows[indexPath.row] = !checkedRows[indexPath.row];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"somecell"];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.accessoryType = checkedRows[indexPath.row] ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*You cannot rely on modifying `cell` directly*

Instead, modify the underlying data, then call `[self.tableView reloadData]`. In `cellForRowAtIndexpath`, depending on data for that index path, set the accessories accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
           if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
               cell.accessoryType = hasGroupID ? UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton : UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
           else
               cell.accessoryType = hasGroupID ? UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton : UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    } else if (cell.accessoryType != UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: i think for the first time it goes right,but after selection it sticks with check mark